# Como ocultar el texto que sobrepase de un div

Tags: angular, bootstrap, ionic

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este punto mi texto de "Due on May 14th" sobrepasa el renglon, y quiero que se conserve en la misma linea solo que se vea de la siguiente forma:

"Due on May..." Se le agregan unos puntos al final de la palabra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar las siguientes propiedades de css

```
white-space: nowrap; /*No salto de lineas*/
overflow: hidden; /*No dejar que salga nada*/
text-overflow: ellipsis; /*Colocar los puntos suspencivos*/
```

quedaria como el ejemplo de aqui:

```css
.hidden-text{
  width: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  /*Propiedades*/
  white-space: nowrap; /*No salto de lineas*/
  overflow: hidden; /*No dejar que salga nada*/
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /*Colocar los puntos suspencivos*/
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden-text">
  Hola mundo texto largo
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente, únicamente puse en porcentaje el width, para que se adaptara al responsive, me funciono gracias!